# HttpClient, WebClient which use on Xamarin.Froms

Tags: http, xamarin.forms, httpclient, httpwebrequest, webclient

I'm working on a mobile App on Xamarin.Forms that consuming an API via HTTP. I was wondering what library is better. I'm having troubles because HttpClient for .NET 2.0 doesn't have synchronous requests. I read some posts about it but I don't sure what is most recomended on 2021, use HttpClient, WebClient, HttpWebRequest or other library for Xamarin.Forms. Which of those is better and more simple for my app?

Comment: I know this is a direct answer, but I made very positive experiance with the [Flurl](https://flurl.dev/docs/fluent-http/) library, which is a lightweight wrapper around the HttpClient.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want a synchronous request? Http calls are not returned immediatly.

`HttpClient` is the recommended way to go.

Microsoft has a specific article about `HttpClient` for `Xamarin.Forms`:  [Consume a RESTful web service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/rest).